# Azure Devops Restful API - Token Get Personal Access Token - GET Returns Error - Parameter 'accessTokenKey' cannot be omitted

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

Hello I am needing some assistance using the Azure Devops REST API specifically for the "Token Get Personal Access Token - GET" found on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/token%20get%20personal%20access%20token/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I am performing the following in my code but it returns an error stating that, "Parameter 'accessTokenKey' cannot be omitted".

I tried to add the param accessTokenKey to the URL with my token as the value but still seeing this error and the API in the doc does not mention this param.

My code:

```
let user = "test";
let pass = token; //Set as token as I dont want to share my actual token.
let url = `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/_apis/tokenadmin/tokengetpersonalaccesstoken?isPublic=true&api-version=6.0-preview.1`;
let authorizationBasic = Buffer.from(`${user}:${pass}`).toString("base64");
let config = {
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + authorizationBasic
    }
};

axios.post(`${url}`, { }, config)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I've searched for hours to get to where I am now and this seems to be my stopping point so any assistance to point me in the right direction is appreciated!

The token I'm using has full access and set to all accessible organizations.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue and get same result.

[image]

It return 400 Bad Request. The API you are using which allows token administrators to retrieve personal access token (PAT) details for a specific PAT.

There should be a place to specify the token which you want to fetch info. Also tried add {"accessTokenKey":"token here"} in request body, but still get same result.

Seems there is some lacking of document. Since it's a totally new Rest API and still **under preview**.

Suggest you monitor that official doc and wait for formal version released.

Comment: Thanks Patrick appreciate you at least looking into it.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT six months later, any progress on this issue?