# How to get authentication token using MSAL library for Azure DevOps REST API call?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to get Azure DevOps [PAT list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) using REST API call. I'm using Azure Function App (JavaScript/NodeJS).

I want to get "PAT" list using the REST API. So I'm using the [PAT List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) REST API, but I'm not able to get the list. I'm using the MSAL library for For Authentication. Using this MSAL library I'm able to get the authentication token although I'm unable to get "PAT List".

**How we get "PAT List" ?**

For more clarity I'm adding below our code. If I'm making any mistakes then anyone can rectify me.

```
const config = require('../config');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const clientId = 'config.DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID';
    const clientSecret = 'config.DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET';
    const tenantId = 'config.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID';
 
    let authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
    let authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenantId;

    const configuration = {
        auth: {
            clientId: clientId,
            authority: authorityUrl,
            clientSecret: clientSecret
        }
    };

    // Create msal application object
    const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(configuration);
    // With client credentials flows permissions need to be granted in the portal by a tenant administrator.
    // The scope is always in the format "<resource>/.default"
    const clientCredentialRequest = {
        scopes: ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"], // replace with your resource
    };

    const credentials = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest);

    const tokenType = credentials.tokenType;
    const token = credentials.accessToken;
    const apiToken = `${tokenType} ${token}`;  // 'Bearer <token>'

    let url = `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=6.1-preview.1`;
    const header = {
        Authorization: `${apiToken}`
    };

    const result = await rp({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: header,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        method: 'GET'
    });

    context.res = {
        body: result
    };
}
```

**Output:** After run the above code I'm getting the below result as HTML.

[image]

I'm not getting the proper response. Getting the above response as HTML view.

Comment: You'll need to provide the result and status code, as it's not immediately obvious. It could be a problem with the credential grant, for example, or a problem with the request construction.

Comment: Hi @Param ,Have you referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440589/azure-devops-restful-api-token-get-personal-access-token-get-returns-error

Comment: Hi WaitingForGuacamole, please check above. I have updated the output.

Comment: Hi ShrutiJoshi-MT, I have applied the same as you referred, but I'm getting error.

Comment: MSAL will acquire the token by showing the standard user interface for Sign In, you need to test this from a browser for that flow to happen...not via postman.